# Eclipse crashes while trying to export application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried to export my android application and it just crashed with the following code. Tried several times still the error stays glued. Anyway out of this?

Following is the Log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007fea9e58ee3e, pid=4241, tid=140644277511936
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b14) (build 1.7.0_55-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x98e3e]  envz_strip+0x61e
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140624/eclipse/hs_err_pid4241.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 0):

First right click on the project and refresh it. Then export it using archive file.
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @peaseful_Warrior "export it using archive file" can you explain that?

Comment: @Kailas I edited the answer. Sorry it was not clear before. Check if it solves the problem.